# lambda for sort order - can a variable be used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, odata

I have a C# MVC project. I want to build statement in client app controller method to fetch JSON from web.api, for paging/sort in the view template. Can the sort order be passed to this code as a variable?

```
var container = new CourseService.Container(uri);
var query = container.Courses.OrderByDescending(c => c.Name).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

Comment: No you can't, you need to do something like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078465/want-a-query-to-make-order-by-variable-in-linq-query][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078465/want-a-query-to-make-order-by-variable-in-linq-query

Comment: Thanks Chris. Thought so...but wanted to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add your own `IEnumerable` extension to do this?

```
public enum SortOrder
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> input,
        Func<T, TKey> keySelector, SortOrder order)
    {
        switch(order)
        {
            case SortOrder.Descending:
                return input.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
            default:
                return input.OrderBy(keySelector);
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var output = container.Courses.OrderBy(c => c.Name, SortOrder.Descending);
```

Comment: Ant Thanks for code. I'm a C# newbie. My controller method and variable parameter is in code below. How do I implement your code?  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
         public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder)
        {

Comment: If you drop the `EnumerableExtensions` class and `SortOrder` enum somewhere into your codebase then you can just call it like I demonstrated above. If you want to use strings, you can adapt the method to take a string instead of a `SortOrder` but that's less robust as you lose the compile-time checking (i.e. you have to ensure that you get the string right every time). Better would be to change your controller action so that it looks like: `public ViewResult Index(SortOrder sortOrder)`.